# Setting faces is slow?

Tags: buffers, faces, minibuffer, performance

I'm seeing rather bizarre behavior. I have the following code:

```el
(defun set-mode-line-face ()
  (let ((color
          (pcase (random 6)
            (`1  '("#586e75" . "#eee8d5"))
            (`2   '("#859900" . "#eee8d5"))
            (`3  '("#93a1a1" . "#073642"))
            (`4  '("#268bd2" . "#eee8d5"))
            (`5 '("#dc322f" . "#eee8d5"))
            (other    '("grey70" . "black")))))

    (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
      :background (car color)
      :foreground (cdr color))

    (set-face-foreground 'mode-line-buffer-id (cdr color))))

;; Change modeline color by Evil state
(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'set-mode-line-face)
```

Strangely enough, this causes emacs to become nearly unusable (~0.2s delays abound). Is the overhead of setting a face really that high? Is there any way I can fix it?

This is `Emacs 24.5` on a graphical Linux frame.

Comment: Try pre-constructing the six faces and rewrite the mode line format variables like `mode-line-buffer-identification` instead -- it might be faster (I haven't tested it).

Comment: If the faces already exist -- e.g., defined with `defface`, then use those.  If you are **changing** an existing face, then `face-remap-add-relative` will be much faster than `set-face-attribute`.  See this related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25150669/2112489  You have already discovered the reason *not* to use `set-face-attribute` when adjusting the mode-line colors.  The `set-face-background` likely suffers the same lag.

Comment: @lawlist that does the trick! Would you mind posting an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the speed at which the mode-line needs to update, it is too costly to use functions like `set-face-attribute`, `set-face-foreground`, and `set-face-background`.  The most efficient method of setting mode-line faces will be to use either ones that have already been defined -- e.g., `defface` -- or, by modifying existing faces with `face-remap-add-relative`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html

The following is a quote from *Stefan* in the related thread at the following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150669/2112489

"Changing faces dynamically is going to be slow because the redisplay code is written under the assumption that faces don't change (if they change, we basically redo a lot of work).  Using `face-remapping-alist` will result in much better performance because the redisplay code does expect it to change and know how to cache the result."

Comment: `face-remap-add-relative` works wonderfully!